# How to stop main thread to complete all Mono calls?

Tags: java, spring-reactive, spring-mono

I'm making multiple mono calls to DB.And result of all Mono response  is needed to compute final result which is written after declared Mono logic.

```
if (SomeObject.getAccountLevelActiveList() != null) {

                SomeObject.getAccountLevelActiveList().parallelStream().forEach(account -> {
                    Mono<SubLine> subLineMono= SubLineService
                            .getLineLevelCustProfile(preNbsLineLevelConverter.getSubLine(account ));
                

                    subLineMono.subscribe(subLine-> PollObject.getSubList()
                            .put(accountLevelMtn.getMtn(), Optional.ofNullable(subLine)));

                });

            }
```

But my main logic is getting executed before mono result stored to the **PollObject**. so i'm getting null in the **PollObject**. So i want to stop my main thread until Mono results stored into the **PollObject**.

Comment: You generally should be chaining your "main logic" off of the reactive pipeline.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yes, i have main logic after if block execution by passing 'PollObject'.

Comment: I understand, and I'm saying to move that logic _into_ the reactive pipeline.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your comment.@chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop main thread then you can use  blocking instead of subscribing, but you must first convert the `List` into `Flux` and then `flatMap`-it using provided `Mono`. The logic you have in the `subscribe` method can be moved into a side effect operator `doOnNext` either of the `Mono` or the wrapping `Flux`:

```java
Flux.fromIterable(SomeObject.getAccountLevelActiveList())
    .flatMap(account ->
        SubLineService.getLineLevelCustProfile(
            preNbsLineLevelConverter.getSubLine( account ))
    ).doOnNext(subLine ->
        PollObject.getSubList().put(accountLevelMtn.getMtn(),
            Optional.ofNullable(subLine))
    ).blockLast();
    // the following code will be executed first when all monos are completed
```

If your code following the `if` is not required to run in the main thread, it would be better stay reactive as the @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic already suggested. Use `reduce` operator to put all the result together producing mono that is completed when all the provided monos are completed:

```java
Flux.fromIterable(SomeObject.getAccountLevelActiveList())
    .flatMap(account ->
        SubLineService.getLineLevelCustProfile(
            preNbsLineLevelConverter.getSubLine( account ))
    ).reduce(PollObject.getSubList(), (subList, subLine) ->
        sublist.put(accountLevelMtn.getMtn(), Optional.ofNullable(subLine))
    ).map(subList -> {
        // the code here will be executed first when all monos are completed
    })
    // ... other operators if necessary
    // eventually subscribing or returning the mono for further processing 
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: great..very usefull